# Why does JPA(Hibernate) with ddl-auto: update start very slowly?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hibernate starts very slowly(About 5 to 20 minutes) when `ddl-auto: update`, not if it is `none`. After debugging, I found the code eventually stopped at the while loop in method `populateTablesWithColumns` of `org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl` class.

Code of this method:

```
private void populateTablesWithColumns(
        String catalogFilter,
        String schemaFilter,
        NameSpaceTablesInformation tables) {
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = extractionContext.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData().getColumns(
                catalogFilter,
                schemaFilter,
                null,
                "%"
        );
        try {
            String currentTableName = "";
            TableInformation currentTable = null;
            while ( resultSet.next() ) {
                if ( !currentTableName.equals( resultSet.getString( "TABLE_NAME" ) ) ) {
                    currentTableName = resultSet.getString( "TABLE_NAME" );
                    currentTable = tables.getTableInformation( currentTableName );
                }
                if ( currentTable != null ) {
                    final ColumnInformationImpl columnInformation = new ColumnInformationImpl(
                            currentTable,
                            DatabaseIdentifier.toIdentifier( resultSet.getString( "COLUMN_NAME" ) ),
                            resultSet.getInt( "DATA_TYPE" ),
                            new StringTokenizer( resultSet.getString( "TYPE_NAME" ), "() " ).nextToken(),
                            resultSet.getInt( "COLUMN_SIZE" ),
                            resultSet.getInt( "DECIMAL_DIGITS" ),
                            interpretTruthValue( resultSet.getString( "IS_NULLABLE" ) )
                    );
                    currentTable.addColumn( columnInformation );
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            resultSet.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw convertSQLException(
                e,
                "Error accessing tables metadata"
        );
    }
}
```

The database used by the project is `Oracle 11g`(may be more than 3000 tables and millions of rows of data), Hibernate version is `5.4.x`, and the type of `resultSet` object in the loop body is `com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet`.

This is the invoke stack information when I debugging:

```
populateTablesWithColumns:368, InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl (org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal)
getTables:341, InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl (org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal)
getTablesInformation:120, DatabaseInformationImpl (org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal)
performTablesMigration:65, GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl (org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal)
performMigration:207, AbstractSchemaMigrator (org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal)
doMigration:114, AbstractSchemaMigrator (org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal)
performDatabaseAction:184, SchemaManagementToolCoordinator (org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi)
process:73, SchemaManagementToolCoordinator (org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi)
<init>:318, SessionFactoryImpl (org.hibernate.internal)
build:468, SessionFactoryBuilderImpl (org.hibernate.boot.internal)
build:1259, EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl (org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal)
createContainerEntityManagerFactory:58, SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider (org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor)
createNativeEntityManagerFactory:365, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (org.springframework.orm.jpa)
buildNativeEntityManagerFactory:409, AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (org.springframework.orm.jpa)
afterPropertiesSet:396, AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean (org.springframework.orm.jpa)
afterPropertiesSet:341, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (org.springframework.orm.jpa)
invokeInitMethods:1863, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
initializeBean:1800, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doCreateBean:620, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
createBean:542, AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
lambda$doGetBean$0:335, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getObject:-1, AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$293/0x0000000800e57b40 (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getSingleton:234, DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
doGetBean:333, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:208, AbstractBeanFactory (org.springframework.beans.factory.support)
getBean:1154, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
finishBeanFactoryInitialization:908, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
refresh:583, AbstractApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.support)
refresh:145, ServletWebServerApplicationContext (org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context)
refresh:780, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
refreshContext:453, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
run:343, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
run:1370, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
run:1359, SpringApplication (org.springframework.boot)
main:19, GroupApplication (com.mycompany.group)
```

What trouble has happened here? Any answers or improvements(Including replacement of JPA implementation) are welcome and thankful.

Thanks very much :)

Comment: How many entities do you have?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I don't have many entities, about 5~20 in total.

Comment: @Simon Martinelli This project uses MyBatis-Plus as the persistence framework. JPA was introduced when I take over the project, and now there are two persistence frameworks. I guess the JPA slow was not caused by MyBatis-Plus.

Comment: 'ddl-auto' is NOT part of JPA. As you can see, Hibernate is getting the metadata for your 3000 tables and determining which, if any, are what it needs to use for the defined entities, and what modifications it might need to make to them. This is why DDL features are a developer tools. If you need specific tables create in specific ways, generate a script and use that during deployment or at specific times instead of every time you restart the application.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the explanation. Is there a way to improve it? I'm not using DDL for production, I just want Hibernate to help me create some new tables and print the resulting SQL statements because I don't want to write them by hand.

Comment: Create option sometimes is faster in some JPA providers, as it will just generate and execute create table statements without need to check the existing metadata. But if you are looking to modify existing tables; no. Only option there might be to pick a database that has fewer tables visible so the scope is smaller.